# How can you use an array within a struct like a normal array in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Been at this for a minute. Doesn't look like an array declared in a struct isn't the same as one declared outside of a struct.

Given...

```
struct TestArr {
 uint256[] _numbers;
}
 
struct TestStruct {
  TestArr numbers;
}

_mapping[0] = TestStruct(
 TestArr(anArray)
)
```

Does `_mapping[0].numbers` act as a normal array? How do you check its `length`? How would you do something like `_mapping[0].numbers.length` or `_mapping[0].numbers[0]`

Comment: What makes you think that it behaves differently?

Comment: Because the mapping returns a struct, and that populated tuple is not a normal type correct? I'm not entirely sure how to access the tuple like a normal array.

That tuple looking like this `tuple uint256() 10,11,12`. How would I access `10` for example? <-- If you iterate over numbers and use `_mapping[0].numbers.push()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but an array in a struct still behaves like any other array. If `anArray` in your code snippet is `[10, 11, 12]`, you can access 10 with `_mapping[0].numbers._numbers[0]`